# Stop CSS animation on second time page load

Tags: html, css, animation

I am adding an this [animation](http://codepen.io/mrxia/pen/OMXzpx) to a favorite button, which is working fine but when I reload the page then the animation once again runs and which is creating disturbance on listing page. So how can I control or stop the animation on page reload if the favorite button is clicked once and thing has become favorite.

CSS Code:

```css
.event_box .eb_like i:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: url(../img/alike.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
 background-size: 2900%;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
} 
.event_box .eb_like i.like:after{
  -webkit-animation: heart-burst steps(28) 0.8s 1 both;
  animation: heart-burst steps(28) 0.8s 1 both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes heart-burst {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}

@keyframes heart-burst {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do it by creating cookie. If there is no cookie animation runs if cookie is there skip animation. Hope this helps

Comment: It is not possible to check if a page is bookmarked, but what you can do, is store a cookie when someone clicked it, and then, the second time check for the cookie

Answer (score 1):

Actually, one possible solution is to store a key in browser's local storage. You can do something like that:

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/vojrcoa4/

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-love')[0];


btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!window.localStorage.getItem('favorited')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('love')[0].setAttribute('id', '');
        window.localStorage.setItem('favorited',true);
    },1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no way you can do that by css only, there are two ways both involving some coding:

1. (easy) you can set a cookie via js and use it to check if that
   element has been clicked
2. (over complicated) if the user is logged in you can save that action in a database and when he reload the page you check the db and print the appropriate class